# Convert auto-layout (constraints) from xib/storyboard to code?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a xib with UIViewController with auto-layout. But I can't use visual xib/storyboard files at all for some reason.

Is there any common approach/tutorial/library which helps to convert autolayout/constraints to code?

Comment: You can give constraints by code also . Use this : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/

Comment: There is a tool (Disclaimer: I'm the author of it) which converts Xib/Storyboard files to Swift source code. You will need to put generated code into the appropriate View or ViewController. https://microcodingapps.com/products/decode.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at this : https://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout

(Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a lot of libraries.

[This is a page with short description of the most popular ones.](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout)

I use Objective-C so I chose `KeepLayout`. If this project used swift code then the best solution could be [Neon](https://github.com/mamaral/Neon)